# Apple ID issues

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, iphone

I had an iPhone 4s and took over my husband's iPhone 5.  We reset all content and settings.  It has been a nightmare!  I could only sync 5 of many ringtones on the iPhone 5.

After being on the phone with Apple Support for an hour, they were unable to figure out my issue. So I ended up repurchasing all my ringtones!

1. I've noticed that under 'Settings->iTunes & App Stores' the Apple ID is my own, however, when I try to update any apps, it's my husband's Apple ID.
2. I've confirmed that it is syncing under my own iTunes account.

I don't know how I'm logged on to 2 different users and why my apps are linked to his Apple ID. I've tried logging out and back in and syncing the phone again (making sure it's my account).

Answer (score 1):

If an application was originally downloaded using your husband's account it will be associated with his account.

An easy way to tell what apps are linked to his Apple ID is to go to your Apps Library in iTunes on your computer. Select an app and press command+i on your keyboard (control+i on Windows). This will get info about the app. Make sure you are on the Summary tab and there will be a field that shows the associated Apple ID.

This kind of situation can be avoided by each of you having a different user account and different iTunes Library on the computer you sync with.

To get your phone to stop asking for his password when you update apps, you will need to delete any apps that are associated with his ID and redownload them using your iTunes account.